# Set up ubuntu server 22.04 image for cloud usage on Digital Ocean

Tags: server, virtualization, 22.04, cloud, cloud-init

I am trying to prepare an ubuntu image for deployment on the digital ocean cloud, I have been following [this tutorial for ubuntu 18.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-digitalocean-droplet-from-an-ubuntu-iso-format-image)

In the tutorial they ask me to remove the `50-curtin-networking.cfg` file from `/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d` directory, but in ubuntu 22.04 that file is not present, the only files in the directory are listed below:

```
customuser@temporary-name:/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d$ ls
05_logging.cfg  99-installer.cfg             README
90_dpkg.cfg     curtin-preserve-sources.cfg  subiquity-disable-cloudinit-networking.cfg
```

It also tells me to go to `/etc/netplan` and delete the `50-cloud-init.yaml` file, but here is the `ls` output for the directory:

```
customuser@temporary-name:/etc/netplan$ ls
00-installer-config.yaml
```

When I import my `.vhdx` image from HyperV Manager into the digital ocean cloud, it can provision a droplet (compute instance) but then it will refuse to connect, and pings will time out.

How can I correctly set up ubuntu server 22.04 for automatic deployment?

Comment: You weren't actually following the tutorial - it uses VirtualBox.

Comment: @OrganicMarble yes but the ubuntu is still an ubuntu and would be the same on virtual box